# Proxying Docker container for outgoing connections

Tags: docker, iptables

My application need access webservice requires white list IP.
Since I have many app servers, i end up a solution like this

`iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT  -p tcp --dport 80  -d a.webservices.dimension.abc.com -j DNAT --to 52.1.2.3:9999`

that means outgoing connection to a.webservices.dimension.abc.com will be routed to 52.1.2.3:9999 ( a proxy server )

It works.

And now I move my application server ( ec2 vm) to Docker container. But doing this, the iptables rule doesn't work.

here is the final rules

`Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCALChain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere            !127.0.0.0/8          ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere              1.2.3.4        tcp dpt:http to:52.1.2.3:9999
Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
MASQUERADE  all  --  ip-172-17-0-0.us-west-2.compute.internal/16  anywhere
MASQUERADE  tcp  --  ip-172-17-0-2.us-west-2.compute.internal  ip-172-17-0-2.us-west-2.compute.internal  tcp dpt:http
Chain DOCKER (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 2/min burst 5 LOG level warning prefix "DOCKER CHAIN "
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:9090 to:172.17.0.2:80`

As a result, the following command d

`docker exec -it some-nginx curl -iL 1.2.3.4`

doesn't work

BUT 
`curl -iL 1.2.3.4`

works

I don't know why. 
Proxying outgoing connection from Docker container should be common but I haven't found out any existing solution.

Please help.

**UPDATE**
The following link 
https://serverfault.com/questions/734526/whitelisting-outgoing-traffic-from-docker-containers
shed me some lights.

use this rule to make it work

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i docker0 -p tcp a.webservices.dimension.abc.com -j DNAT --to 52.1.2.3:9999`

Comment: Use this rule to make it work.
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i docker0 -p tcp a.webservices.dimension.abc.com -j DNAT --to 52.1.2.3:9999